# NodeJS error on established https connection

Tags: node.js

I want to establish https request to my **api** and i have written following lines of code in NodeJS function:

```
function getUsers() {
    /**
     * HOW TO Make an HTTP Call - GET
     */
    // options for GET
    var optionsget = {
        host: 'localhost', // here only the domain name
        // (no http/https !)
        port: 3000,
        path: '/api/users', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
        method: 'GET' // do GET
    };

    console.info('Options prepared:');
    console.info(optionsget);
    console.info('Do the GET call');

    // do the GET request
    var reqGet = https.request(optionsget, function (res) {
        console.log('Requested');
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        console.log("headers: ", res.headers);
        res.on('data', function (d) {
            console.info('GET result:\n');
            process.stdout.write(d);
            console.info('\n\nCall completed');
        });

    });

    reqGet.end();
    reqGet.on('error', function (e) {
        console.error('Last error:' + e);
    });
}
```

**Server side code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require("mysql");
var md5 = require('MD5');
var rest = require("./REST.js");

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

function REST() {
    var self = this;
    self.connectMysql();
}

REST.prototype.connectMysql = function () {
    var self = this;
    var pool = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit: 100,
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'oes_api',
        debug: false
    });
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            self.stop(err);
        } else {
            self.configureExpress(connection);
        }
    });
};

REST.prototype.configureExpress = function (connection) {
    var self = this;
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    var router = express.Router();
    app.use('/api', router);
    app.use('/', index);
    app.use('/users', users);
    var rest_router = new rest(router, connection, md5);
    self.startServer();
};

REST.prototype.startServer = function () {
    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log("All right! I am alive at Port 3000.");
    });
};

REST.prototype.stop = function (err) {
    console.log("ISSUE WITH MYSQL \n" + err);
    process.exit(1);
};

new REST();
```

But https connection is not establishing saying **Last error:Error: socket hang up**.

Could you please help me out to get ride out from this error.

Comment: what does server side code look like?...provide some details..

Comment: Question is edited and following link is totally fine to me (returning JSON objects): http://localhost:3000/api/users/

Comment: For https request port should be 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can create your server using https. Take a look at [this page](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) in the Node Documentation for doing so.

**Example**

```
const https = require('https');

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000);
```